# AWS S3 PHP getObject() getting error Directory [path] does not exist for sink value of [URL]

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download image from AWS S3. I managed using putObject() to upload it to the server, now I would like to download it again. This is my script:

```
  $result = $s3->getObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
  'Key'    => $key,
  'SaveAs' => $filepath
  ));
```

I expect it to download to my folder (permissions set to 777). It does not happen. I get following error:
Directory [path] does not exist for sink value of [URL]

While the directory exists. I have tested the URL of the same directory in the browser to open file and it works.

Comment: All I can see is that exact error string is generated via the condition `!is_dir(dirname($sink))` in `GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php`. Can't be anything other than the directory not existing. `$filepath` is your local file system right? What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I just checked the latest version of the SDK, that error should be printing in the following format, `Directory [PATH'sParent] does not exist for sink value of [PATH]` due to `sprintf('Directory %s does not exist for sink value of %s',dirname($sink),$sink)`, the "sink" value is used twice here.